# put query params inside a filter key laravel

Tags: laravel

hi i want to change this url from get form

http://127.0.0.1:8000/allfiles?category_id=1&file_id=1

to this in laravel

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/allfiles?filter[category_id]=1&filter[file_id]=1](http://127.0.0.1:8000/allfiles?filter%5Bcategory_id%5D=1&filter%5Bfile_id%5D=1)

how can i do that?

Actually i want change perquery=? to filter[perquery]=?

thanks

Comment: Please share more details. How do you generate the URL? What's the problem in changing the generation process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this in the blade (you can modify it if need):

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/allfiles" method="GET">
  <input name="filter['category_id']">
  <input name="filter['file_id']">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks it works but why show like this in link `http://127.0.0.1:8000/allfiles?filter%5Bcategory_id%5D=1`

Comment: as the URL contains special characters like "[" or "]", then it will encode them. The browser encode the URLs automatically. You can check them also with online tools like [this](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/). Don't worry about that, in the backend you can grab that params

Comment: if it's not important, you can change the form method to POST, but in that case don't forget to add @csrf in the form